# How to set border radius on SearchBar (.NET MAUI)?

Tags: c#, maui

How can I set a border radius on search bar?

I've already tried many ways to change this (for example, tried to explicitly specify the tag < Border >), but there are no tags associated with this property in the search bar.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the border to set the corner radius.

```
 <Border Stroke="#C49B33"
         StrokeThickness="1"
         StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10"
         WidthRequest="250"
         Padding="2,8"
         HorizontalOptions="Center">

         <SearchBar></SearchBar>

 </Border>
```

Here is the sample:

[image]

Comment: But how in code behind?

Comment: See [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/border) on how to do it in code behind.

Comment: Code behind approach: myBorder.StrokeShape = new RoundRectangle() { CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(10) }